# Hide picklist field on Task Object

Tags: picklist

Can you give me an idea on how to hide a picklist field upon creation of a new Task and then show it that picklist after successfully creating a New Task. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit the field after record creation?

Comment: @AlinParaschiv yes

Comment: This is a hard one, essentially you have the same user that accesses both pages, so the permissions are the same. Guessing that you want to achieve this using very little code/customization, I think the best bet will be either somehow having 2 page layouts(one for record creation and one for record view) or using some sort of customization for record creation(visual flow, VF, LWC) where you don't include the picklist and a page layout where you include it

Comment: @AlinParaschiv Thank you so much for the idea.